# TypeError: 'value' in Matplotlib, an instance of str or bytes, not a float

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

I cannot figure out why I'm getting a value type error in the first line of my code.
I've looked at the other answers to TypeError problems, but cannot see the error.

My Modules

```py
from datetime import datetime  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib.animation as animation   
import matplotlib as mpl   
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager  
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'  
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Lato'  
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd
```

My Dataframe looks like this
|   |           | Count | Non-Null | Dtype          |
|---|-----------|-------|----------|----------------|
| 0 | DATE      | 1305  | non-null | datetime64[ns] |
| 1 | EFFR      | 1305  | non-null | object         |
| 2 | PRONTSYD  | 1306  | non-null | object         |
| 3 | RRPONTSYD | 1306  | non-null | object         |
| 4 | RPTSYD    | 1306  | non-null | object         |
| 5 | RRPTSYD   | 1306  | non-null | object         |

The error occurs on the first line of the code below

```py
stirs = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SOMA/FRED_reserves/SOMArates2.csv',\
                   verbose =True , warn_bad_lines = True, \
                   usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5], parse_dates=['DATE'] )
stirs.info()  
stirs.columns = stirs.columns.str.strip()  
stirs['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(stirs['DATE'],format='%m/%d/%Y')  
date = stirs.loc[:, "DATE"]  
eff  = stirs.loc[:, "EFFR"]  
repo = stirs.loc[:, "RPONTSYD"]  
rrepo = stirs.loc[:, "RRPONTSYD"]  
mrepo = stirs.loc[:, "RPTSYD"]  
mrrepo = stirs.loc[:, "RRPTSYD"]  
print(eff)  
print(mrrepo)  
x=stirs['DATE']
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2.7), layout='constrained')
plt.plot(x, eff, label='Effective Fed Funds')  [**]
plt.plot(x, repo, label='Repos')
plt.plot(x, rrepo, label='Reverse repo')  
plt.plot(x, mrepo, label='Repos_OMO')  
plt.plot(x, mrrepo, label='Reverse Repos_OMO')  
plt.xlabel('Date')  
plt.ylabel('y label')  
plt.title("Effective FF rate, repo, reverse repo")  
plt.legend()  
plt.savefig('C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SOMA/Soma_stirs.eps')
```

|  |  | Count | Non-Null | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | DATE | 1305 | non-null | datetime64[ns] |
| 1 | EFFR | 1305 | non-null | object |
| 2 | PRONTSYD | 1306 | non-null | object |
| 3 | RRPONTSYD | 1306 | non-null | object |
| 4 | RPTSYD | 1306 | non-null | object |
| 5 | RRPTSYD | 1306 | non-null | objectplt.show() |

I get this error from the code above:

```py
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float
```

Comment: Are empty data cells, cells with just a period, the problem? Here are the first rows of the data:                                                                                                                            
5/16/2017 0.91 . . . 
5/17/2017 0 . 167.158 . 167.158    
5/18/2017 0.91 . 185.287 . 185.287  
5/19/2017 0.91 . 182.273 . 182.273  
5/22/2017 0.91 . 185.031 . 185.031  
5/23/2017 0.91 . 198.865 . 198.865    
5/24/2017 0.91 0.022 184.946 0.022 184.946

Comment: I dont know how to format data on separate rows.  2 spaces at end of each row didnt work. Apologies

Comment: I added statement stirs.fillna(0) but got same TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float, called at first plot line: plt.plot(x, eff, label='Effective Fed Funds').  x is a date, x= stirs['DATE']

Comment: the data, DATE EFFR RPONTSYD RRPONTSYD RPTSYD RRPTSYD DATER   TOTRESNS  
5/16/2017 0.91 . . . . 5/1/1959 18.6  
5/17/2017 . . 167.158 . 167.158 6/1/1959 18.5  
5/18/2017 0.91 . 185.287 . 185.287 7/1/1959 18.7    
5/19/2017 0.91 . 182.273 . 182.273 8/1/1959 18.6  
5/22/2017 0.91 . 185.031 . 185.031 9/1/1959 18.6  
5/23/2017 0.91 . 198.865 . 198.865 10/1/1959 18.6  
5/24/2017 0.91 0.022 184.946 0.022 184.946 11/1/1959 18.6    
5/25/2017 0.91 . 153.451 . 153.451 12/1/1959 19  
5/26/2017 0.91 . 168.041 . 168.041 1/1/1960 18.8

Comment: There are 6 columns of data:   DATE EFFR RPONTSYD RRPONTSYD RPTSYD RRPTSYD  
Matplotlib has no problem plotting the last 4 variable: RPONTSYD RRPONTSYD RPTSYD RRPTSYD  
But the line for plotting the first variable EFFR triggers the error: 
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float  

EFFR is the first variable after DATE, so I'm thinking that the problem is the date format:   the date in csv file is m/d/Y but python records it as Y/m/d